# Want to access the Laravel website with Android application and get the JSON data

Tags: php, android, json, laravel

My website can output the JSON data and my website is using the Laravel 5.2. I can't upload to my server cause the version is not the same. I am thinking doing the Android application which allow the user login and CRUD using the application.

Is that any possible I can use the Android application and create the login function? And login with the account same with my website?

The flow is easy, I have to do the login first.
Then perform the task create an event, pass back the event to my server. And perform task delete, edit. Because it is the first time I am using Laravel, I have no idea how to open the API, and my server didn't support the website.

- my server PHP version is 5.4, it's a hostgator server, shared hosting.
- I want to publish my website online, so then can open the API for mobile application like Android application.
- I have tried OAuth, but it looks complex and I try to find another way or a proper step.

Comment: Please elaborate more, focus on the issue and explain what is wrong, what did you try and what did you reach so that we can help you.

Comment: What do you mean "my server didnt support the website" ? where are you going to put your Laravel app?

Comment: I have updated the question, hope you guys can understand what i am trying to do. And i wish to publish laravel website to online first. About the phone apps, i want do the login function for start. Is that possible to do with the html5?

Comment: Do you mean that you will have an Android APP and want to use the login credentials of your web application?

Comment: @laerte ya, that is what i want to do

Comment: I didn't do this on Laravel yet, but I've coded an application once that had the same behavior but I used Ruby on Rails. The main thing you have to do is to use the authentication token to send or request data. You'll use a standard route and will access it through the Android App. Rails has a lib to make the login through a route and receive the token. I think Laravel should have something like this too... Hope it helps...